# Javascript - remove element from an array if the id in parent of an element is also in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has parent-child values. I need to remove the elements from the array if its parent is already there in the array.

Sample data:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    parentIds: []
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    parentIds: []
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    parentIds: ["1"]
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    parentIds: ["1", "3"]
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    parentIds: ["6"]
  }
]
```

The expected output is:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    parentIds: []
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    parentIds: []
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    parentIds: ["6"]
  }
]
```

I tried with the following code:

```
for (let i = selectedItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (let j = selectedItems.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (selectedItems[j].parentsIds.includes(selectedItems[i].id)) {
          selectedItems.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }
```

But this fails with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` after splicing first match.

It there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: What if only *some* of its parents are there?  Should it be removed?  e.g. if there was `parentIds: ["1", "6"]`.  "1" exists but "6" does not.  What happens in that case?

Comment: @Wyck: The expected output covers that...

Comment: @Cerbrus, no it doesn't.  All of the excluded items had either all of its parentIds not present or all of its parentIds present.  There was no example with a mix.

Comment: Ah okay.... Well, I'd assume that _"if its parent is already there in the array."_ means _any_ parent Id.

Comment: Yeah, any parent id would result in removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your data, to remove all items where [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the `parentIds` are found in your data:

```js
const data = [
  { id: "1", parentIds: [] },
  { id: "2", parentIds: [] },
  { id: "3", parentIds: ["1"] },
  { id: "4", parentIds: ["1", "3"] },
  { id: "5", parentIds: ["6"] }
];

const result = data.filter(
  row => !row.parentIds.some(
    id => data.some(d => d.id === id)
  )
);
      
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First get an array of all id's using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Then use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove those where [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) does not  [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in `allIds`

```js
let data = [{id: "1", parentIds: [] }, {id: "2", parentIds: [] }, {id: "3", parentIds: ["1"] }, {id: "4", parentIds: ["1", "3"] }, {id: "5", parentIds: ["6"] } ];

const allIds = data.map(d => d.id);

data = data.filter((d, x) => !d.parentIds.some(a => allIds.includes(a)));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First extract an array of ids in the original array:

```
const ids = data.map(el => el.id)
```

Then filter the original array intersecting each element's parents array with the extracted ids array:

```
data.filter(el => el.parentIds.filter(parentId => ids.includes(parentId)).length === 0);
```

See this question [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) for an explanation of how array intersection works.